Why are mRNAs polyadenylated as opposed to any other polynucleotide?
During processing, the vast majority of mRNAs recieve a polyadenine (poly-A) tail. The function of this tail is not the subject of my question, but the reason it is specifically adenine, as opposed to any other nucleotide?
I have heard that adenine was the first nucleotide, and that's why it is chosen for this. This would also explain why ATP and NADP are preferred over other nucleotides for their roles (related), but it seems like a hollow explanation, after all, the RNA world hypothesis posits that RNA was the first nucleic acid, yet information is encoded on DNA in modern organisms due to RNA's unsuitability (Wikipedia).
Furthermore, other energy carriers, such as GTP exist, but a poly-G tail is, as far as I can tell, never observed. (related)

“I have heard that adenine was the first nucleotide”. From whom? How does he know? Citation please.

@David As far as I remember, it was my professor that told me that. However, I cannot find any sources to back it up.

Short Answer
As with many evolutionary ‘Why?’ questions, we do not  and cannot know.
General Possibilities
It is good to be aware of the general types of answer to this sort of question, as it avoids one assuming one type of explanation.

The selected alternative is functionally superior to the alternatives.

The selected alternative is the result of pure chance.

Evolution of the selected alternative used more abundant and/or pre-existing chemical intermediates or enzymes

Evolution of the selected alternative involved fewer new enzyme-catalysed reactions.


All one can do is see if any alternatives can either be eliminated or have strong support. My own approach in this respect is illustrated in two separate answers I provided to another question related to ATP.
The current Example
Regarding adenine and polyadenylation, there seems nothing to support explanations 1 or 4.
We do not know at what stage the polyadenylation reaction arose in evolutionary history, but it seems likely that it post-dated both the evolution of the other three bases in RNA, and the emergence of ATP as the prime energy carrier. If so, the concentration of ATP in cells would be much higher than that of other ribonucleotide triphosphates, and protein (or even RNA) modules that could bind ATP would already have emerged in enzymes.
Thus, I would tend to an explanation of type 3, although not being able to exclude 4. But as we do not know what form mRNA took in an RNA world, and when polyadenylation arose, we are whistling in the dark.
